# CSS styling Devise Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, devise

I been trying to add some style into my Devise login.  I tried to edit the simplest thing in the registration page, eg changing the 'sign up' text to "something else", but this changes does not reflect on the html page?  Is there some special trick I have to do in Rails for it to pickup/compiles changes in the Devise html.erb?

Thanks

Comment: I tried adding the CSS .. but it doesn't reflect on the html as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another EDIT:

you need to do is set `config.scoped_views = true` inside `config/initializers/devise.rb`

EDIT:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

See under "configuring views". In devise, they use a default view, which will not appear immediately in your project directory.

In short, you will have to run a command like `rails generate devise:views users`
to generate the views. From there, should you be able to edit the html as per normal.

Comment: I just look at it, and it is listed as "en".  I look at the devise.en.yaml also, and it doesn't look like there anything i can change in there.  It look like those are the text for customizing errors messages.

Comment: LoL. I realized that one of my team member already did that.  We have the user with all the new.html.erb inside, but still when i try to change something in that file, it doesn't reflect on the login/signup etc pages?

Comment: Try restarting the application. Then edit again, see if that helps.

Comment: After running `rails g devise:views` you should have a devise folder under your `views` directory. For sign up look for `registrations/new.html.erb` for login look for `sessions/new.html.erb`. You should be able to edit these files directly.

Comment: what is the file path that you are trying to customize?

Comment: I am editing app/view/users/session/new.html.erb.  Instead of having "<h2>Sign in</h2> as a default ... I chance it to <h2>Sign in  asfasfadfdsfasgsdfgfd</h2>, yet my login view doesn't change?  It still show the "Sign Up" and not "Sign Up asfdasdf"

Comment: Check the output from the console, and see which view is it accessing. That might give you a clue.

Comment: The sign in is coming from /users/sign_in .... and not in the session sign in?  is that correct?

Comment: Check this out: http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/589b5ad891842dd ... You might need to turn out `scoped_views` in your devise.rb

Comment: Thanks!  I think i figure it out.  I needed to use rails generate devise:views instead of rails generate devise:user views.  The devise:user(or admin) is used when we want to seperate the user from the admin.

Answer (score 1):

Using this command you will get access to all the Device's pages inside the `app/views` directory, and then you will be able to customize them:

```
rails g devise:views
```